# Should examination questions be ordered in the same way as they are presented?

Tags: exams

I'm writing my midterm and am currently coming up with questions that relate to important course concepts that I want to test. This is being done in a somewhat ad-lib manner, and my questions are out of order in terms of how the concepts were presented in class.   Is there a compelling argument to ensure that the order is the same as that in class?

Comment: I can't imagine a single reason.

Comment: As long as the course concepts are independent, no.

Comment: Mixing the order may be more effective in testing whether the students can decide for themselves which concepts to use in answering each question. Is that a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the questions are not dependent on one another, then in many cases it is better to mix-up the order. Student responses will be less likely do to basic memorization of their notes/material and more likely to reflect higher-level learning.

Answer (score 0):

The only consideration in ordering (beyond randomly) would be where some questions are intended to be harder than others. As students normally answer front-to-back, it may be appropriate to put the harder questions later such that students don't get "put off" by the hard questions early on.

Comment: I deliberately order my exam questions so that they do _not_ increase in difficulty--and I tell students that--because I want students to read all the questions before deciding for themselves which they find easier. (But I do try to put the easiest question first.)

Comment: It depends on the style of exam as well. While choosing questions is customary in my university I feel that it is invalid if the exam is intended as a random sample. In a choose your question exam all questions should be equal in intended difficulty but sub questions can be of different levels.

Comment: _In a choose your question exam all questions should be equal in intended difficulty_ — I strongly disagree.